# CALL with a modified return address

Tags: assembly, x86-64, coroutine

What's the best way to handle a CALL in x64 assembly, that should return to a slightly shifted return address? Mainly concerning efficiency/execution speed. I'll briefly explain what I'm trying to do.

**Background**

I have a custom, interpreted visual scripting language, that gets compiled to native code. This language has builtin stack-based coroutines, and previously they were still handled semi-interpreted (with a separate stack-class to store the coroutine-data). I'm in the process of nativizing it entirely, so that only RSP is used.

One part of those coroutines is the ability for nested yielding, meaning if a coroutine calls another yielding method, that method can internally yield to suspend the entire invokation. This information is handled via a "YieldState" struct, stored in an register. That means, that for the new fully nativized variant, we can just call a yielding method from a coroutine with a call-instruction:

```
call      12345; // [rip+12345] => yieldingMethod
```

At least, in theory. As our coroutines are stack-based, we store local variables plainly on the stack, not in some sort of class like stackless coroutines might do. This requires cleanup (in case the coroutine is destroyed before finishing) to be handled via another method, which I called "interrupt handler". Such interrupt-handler being invoked is quite common in my practical use-case, but not overly so. So my goal was to provide something that is faster than an exception-handler (which usually requires some global lookup of the frame), but doesn't require explicitely setting this address for each call. So what I did was embedd the interrupt-handler address between the call and the return-address - since for the old version of the code, we had to load the return manually, this was not a problem:

```
lea rcx,[rip+25]; // 25 is the assumed byte-size up until the return address
mov rdx,rbx;      // load non-native call stack
call prepareMethodYielding; // stores return-address on stack
jmp 12345;        // actually call our "yieldingMethod"
mov r15,interruptAddress;
```

The last instruction is never executed - we lea the return address to actually skip it. We only have it here to be able to lookup the interrupt-handler. Given a resume-address, we can just decrement the pointer by 8, and we have the address of that resumes interrupt. The "mov r15" in our case is just to allow us to disassemble the code properly; we could just embedd the address alone, but that would confuse any external disassembler.

**The actual problem**

Now in the new version, there is no "prepareMethodYielding", but only a call - at least, optimally. But "call" in itself doesn't allow us to do a modified return-address, so here I'm faced with a few options, and I want to know which one is the best.

*Option A - lea + push + jmp*

Our first option is to simulate the "call", but push the return-address manually:

```
lea         rax,[rip+10h]
push        rax
jmp         A6 // yieldingMethod
```

This requires 3 instructions, but no access to memory.

*Option B - push from memory*

We could reduce the number of options, by storing the return-address in some area of constant-memory:

```
push        qword ptr[rip+1234] // return-address stored here
jmp         A6                  // yieldingMethod
```

Now we need only one push an no intermediate register, though now we need an access to memory, which could potentially be further away in the data-section.

*Option C - modify the return address in the called function*

Another option that I see would be to adjust the return-address that is produced by call inside the called method. All those methods here are compiled using my own calling convention, so they don't adhere to x64 or any other.

```
// caller
call     A6                 // yielding method

// callee, first instruction
add      qword ptr[rsp],10  // size of interrupt-embedding is always the same
```

This would also only be one instruction, with a small encoding. Though just from a design point of view, I don't like it very much, since it couples the information about the embedding of the callee into the caller - though, if this was the most efficient variant, I might still go for it.

*Option D - don't modify the return-address at all*

Our last option is to not modify the return-address at all, but instead change how lookup and return is handled.

```
call      12345;                // yieldingMethod
mov       r15,interruptAddress; // is actually executed now (but value is not used)
```

So here, we would change where we lookup the interrupt-address (as the return-address now points in front of the fake instruction, instead of behind it). Then, upon return from the call, we would execute the movabs instruction, but discard the value is loaded.
The upside here is that overall code-size is the smallest, since we don't need to add any additional instructions that aren't already there. However, we are executing a 10-byte mov instruction, which could be slower than some of the other variants. It kind of depends here on what the CPU is doing - if it already decodes the fake instruction, even if it doesn't directly reach it, it might be the best idea to just execute it, instead of modifying the return address. Same thing, if the CPU can somehow detect that the instruction has no effect, as it's value is never read, during register renaming, then it could effectively be free - atm, I'm using a register that is not used, to distinquish for my own assembler; but then it would probably make sense to use a register that is overwritten soon after, I assume.
Though I'm unsure on what would actually happen here.

**Conclusion**

So, which of those 4 options seems the most efficient to you? I'm also open to other ideas, though the general design of how the coroutines are done is finished and functional, so something like using a statemachine-based approach which IIRC some coroutines use, is not really an option here.

Comment: In my 8086/386 debugger I sometimes need to embed data after a call. Sometimes I choose to modify the near return address on the stack. However, for allowing to debug the debugger itself it is easier to work with a format where the near call is followed by a (strict) short jump, and the data provided to the function is stored after this jump. The jump generally doesn't do anything other than skip this data. I described one format of a call with such a jump in https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/ldebug.htm#eldlinkcall As the jump is directly after the call instruction, the return address is not changed.

Comment: @ecm I'd have to check how this works with my primary runtime disassembler (MSVC). Reason I used "mov" as a prefix for this data is because MSVC is just interpreting asm-data in a forward-fashion. So it might still f*** up the rest of the disassembler stream - I'll test this later. But just in terms of performance, you'd say that jmp over the data is comparable, if not faster than unused "mov" of the same data?

Comment: The jump over data is probably faster than modifying the return address on the stack, as that may mess with the return address prediction. The `mov` to a scratch register that's actually executed is probably equally fast, but your program may benefit from being able to use all registers without reserving one as a scratch register. As for the disassembler, my example will trip it up, but you can insert the additional opcode fragments for your data to result in a "clean" disassembly that recognises your data as the immediate of a (never executed) `mov`.

Comment: Didn't even know return-prediction is a thing, so that's good to know. I don't actually need to reserve a register for using my mov though - at least atm, I don't preserve registers across function calls, especially yielding ones - so that's not an issue right now. EDIT: And even so, I could just use one that x64 considers volatile anyway.

Comment: Fair, in my applications there are no registers considered volatile for all function calls as I choose [the CHG registers](https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/acegals.htm#protocol-chg) individually for every function.

Comment: For option D, the `nop` instruction can actually take an operand. Assuming you don't need the full 64 bits you could do `nop [0x12345678]` Depending on whether you can have the interrupt path be slow, you can also have an external table mapping the return address to the handler. This is similar to what the linux kernel is doing for exceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a variant of option D that could work:

The x86 architecture has a long nop instruction `nop r/m32`, which performs no effect.  The operand of this instruction is ignored and can be a memory operand.  If you use this instruction with a modr/m operand that has a 32 bit displacement, you can effectively embed a 32 bit number in the instruction stream with no harm.

While your interrupt address is a 64 bit address, it could be possible to express it as a 32 bit distance from some base address, permitting you to get away with a shorter encoding.  Or use a pair of such long nop instructions to encode the full 64 bits.

This could look like:

```
call 12345;  // yielding method
nop [rdx+interruptAddress-baseAddress]  // encode interruptAddress
```

---

An advantage to this is that running one NOP after return is even cheaper than an instruction to modify the return address.  More importantly, it avoids a mispredict from the [return-address stack predictor](https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/04/ras-microbenchmarks/#call0) which assumes that `call` and `ret` will be paired the normal way.

Comment: Using 32 bit could actually work. Atm, embedded addresses were a mixture of native c++-functions and custom compiled ones (depending on if locals are used or not). However, for the full nativized variant, I will need to compile specialized handlers for all cases, to be able to properly unwind RSP. Then, any handler would be relative to my one code-buffer, whose base-address I could embedd into the interrupt-entry function (I need one for simulated re-entry into the yielding state now anyway). I'll try that out, thanks.

Comment: @Juliean If you use a RIP-relative addressing mode, you can make it so the offset encoded matches where the debugger things the memory operand points.  This may make it easier to read the disassembled code.

Comment: If you do not require to preserve the arithmetic flags you can also get away with a `test eax, imm32` instruction (like [a skipping instruction](https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/acegals.htm#skipping)) which requires only one opcode byte, 0A9h, to encode 32 bits worth of data.

Comment: If you need more than 32 bits but less than 64, you could use some bits of the ModRM and/or SIB byte.  ModRM is `mode | reg | rm`.  You need `mode` to be fixed (memory with disp32), and one value of R/M implies a SIB, others don't.  So you'd need some bitfield merging like `pdep` if you wanted to use all of Reg and 2 of the 3 bits of R/M.  Or you could just use a fixed ModR/M that implies a SIB and use all 8 bits of it plus a disp32, allowing 40 bits.  (Then you need a 64-bit mask (or 2 shifts).  If you use a 64-bit pext constant, you could get 45 bits, using 3 bits of Reg and 2 from ModR/M.

Comment: Ended up doing it this way, and 32 bit were enough. Since all interrupt-handler are now in the same code segment as the coroutine-code, I could just embedd the interrupt-address as an rip-relative offset, which means I can assemble the full 64 bit-pointer just by adding the embedded data to the address used to fetch it.

Comment: @Juliean Cool!  Make sure to use the correct base.  RIP-relative addresses are relative to the instruction after the one that does the access.

Comment: @fuz Yep, I know they work, have used them before - but thanks anyway :) Also since I do the address assembly manually (there is no actual rip-relative instruction executed), I could be a lot more free in what I make the address relative to - I just chose RIP-mode to make it more conistent with the rest of the code.

Comment: @Juliean Great!  I'm happy it worked out for you.